# How to underline the hyper-link spreaded on two lines. CSS-HTML geeks?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

[image]

I applied the following CSS to the above text. How to make the underline of above hyperlink to be appear as the one below. For example like this one [image]

```
.result-listingext h3 
{

    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#b2002f;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    text-decoration: none; 
    background: white; 
    font-size:0.94em;
    font-weight:normal; 
    line-height:1.3; 
}

    .result-listingext h3 a:visited  
{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    text-decoration: none;  
    background: white; 
    font-size:0.94em;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1.3; 
}   


.result-listingext h3 a:link,
.result-listingext h3 a:hover,
.result-listingext h3 a:focus,
.result-listingext h3 a:active {
    color:#b2002f;
        font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    text-decoration: none;  background: white; 
    font-size:0.94em;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1.3; 
}
```

Comment: whats your question? I don't get it either

Comment: All your CSS classes include `text-decoration:none`, which removes all underlines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make a text underline different from the text's colour, you need `border-bottom`.

```
border-bottom: 1px grey solid;
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QMGfK/2/)

You can use `padding-bottom` / `padding-top` and `line-height` to control the distances between text and border, and each line.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for:

CSS:

```
.myClass a
{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Instead of none like you have.

Comment: I think the problem is that the underline will automatically take the link's text colour

Comment: Aha, well I understood his question differently *before* the edit :)